# Adding ruby on rails to an existing react native app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, react-native, rubygems

**Background**

I'm developing a React Native app for the first time. I've gotten to the point where I need to start working on the back end and I'm going to use Ruby on Rails to do that. I've installed Ruby and SQLite3, and I've successfully added Ruby to my project.

**Problem**

As of right now, when I try to install bcrypt and jwt to the Gemfile in the project, I ran `gem install bcrypt/jwt` and that seemed to work, but when I try to run `bundle` i get an error: "Could not locate Gemfile". I am certain the Gemfile is in the directory I'm running the commands in, as I can see it in VS Code and also going down the path in C:/, etc.

**Question**

Can I actually add Ruby on Rails to an existing project? What could be the cause of this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You say you’ve installed Ruby, but have you install Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Yes, I, even double checked right now and I have Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created a new Rails-App via rails new myapp you can cd into this directory and call bundle install.

```
rails new myApp && cd myApp && bund
```

Please check that you are in the correct directory. If you are sure that you are in the right directory then check your current rails version with `rails --version`.

Make sure you are in the project directory before running bundle install. For example, after running rails new myproject, you will want to cd myproject before running bundle install.

Comment: I'm following [this tutorial](https://scottdomes.com/rails-authentication-deploy/) which means I've used `rails new authentication-boilerplate --api`  instead of your suggestion to use `rails new myApp && cd myApp && bund` any suggestions to go from there?

Comment: Have you tried to `cd` into authentication-boilerplate and then run bundle install? If bundle is not defined or unavailable try running `gem install bundler` before.

Comment: That helped a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`gem install` - like `npm install -g`, programm to fetch gems,
`bundle` is fetching list of gems from `Gemfile` in your app(current folder), like `package.json` (not sure about naming)

*1. Can I actually add Ruby on Rails to an existing project?*

> Yes, sure. You have a lot of variation to do that

- here [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-ruby-on-rails-project-with-a-react-frontend) the good article how create rails-react app, then you can move your front end part to react folder in the new rails application.
- you can create new rails as separated application, in folder what you want as API with option `rails new your_app_name --api`, then send requests from react app directly to rails app port or IP(it is harder to implement, but I think it is right solution).

*2. What could be the cause of this issue?*

- it is possible because you do not have rails app do not exist
- you do not have Gemfile in your folder.

Comment: Thank you for that guide, it didn't solve the issue but it may come in handy in the future. Much appreciated!